# Does visiting Iraq or Iran invalidate an existing B1/B2 visa?

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, iran, iraq

I understand that nationalities eligible for VWP cannot enter the US without seeking clearance and obtaining a sticker visa from US embassies if they have travelled to Iran, Iraq, Syria & Sudan since March 2011.

But what about citizens from countries that require a US visa to travel to the US, what if they have a valid US B1/B2 visa AND visit Iran/Iraq AND then visit the US soon after? Is there anything to suggest that the visit to the restricted countries would invalidate their existing US B1/B2 visa?

Let me add an example: suppose a citizen of Pakistan or Turkey or Lebanon, who holds a US B1/B2 visa which has been used once, visits Iran and Iraq for tourism/pilgrimage purposes and after a few months arrives at the US port of entry and seeks admission. Is there anything wrong with this scenario?

Answer (score 17):

Visiting one of the VWP invalidating countries does not invalidate a visa. That's the whole point, since the VWP invalidation compels the VWP national to obtain a visa, and if it also invalidated the visa there would be no way for such a VWP national to visit the US.

You may get a little more questioning if the border guard knows about the visit, and you certainly shouldn't hide your visit if asked, but the visa is still perfectly valid.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I don't want to hide my visit from the US authorities and they can inspect my passport and interview me at will, but I don't want to get flagged or have anything appended to my travel history as it might cause unforeseen problems in the future. I plan to have a two-week long Iraq trip on VoA and my passport would have entry/exit stamps from Iraqi airports.

Comment: You write as if the visa remaining valid is the only conceivable possibility. But it's easy to imagine a world in which the US forbids entry to anyone who's ever been to Iran or Iraq. It's easy to imagine a world in which the US believes that visiting Iran or Iraq is a big enough change in circumstances that it invalidates your visa but you can apply for a new one, which will be evaluated in the context of the new circumstances. Neither of those things actually happens, but they're _possible_, which is the whole point of the question.

Comment: I'm only writing about the current legal situation.

Comment: The answer is correct however premise is not. Visiting one of those countries **after** acquisition of the USA visa means you never got the heightened scrutiny reserved for people who apply for a visa **after** visiting have to go through.

Answer (score 9):

You'll be fine. They might ask you questions if you get taken to secondary, but that usually only happens if the computer flags a passenger. Source: personal experience.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Is it possible to get flagged just by having visited one of the restricted countries or does it take something more than that? And could you please explain what happens in secondary?

Comment: What happens in secondary is more intense questioning; in your case, about what business (or family) you had in Iran and Iraq. I don't think the system is smart enough to flag you in advance because I am 100% certain the US and Iran do not exchange visa information(!), but the border guard is highly likely to notice your visas for these countries.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. You're right, Iran and US don't share visa info but Iraq does. But is it a problem if I have a two-week visit only to Iraq with VoA and entry/exit stamps? Would that get me flagged? The thing is, I don't want to hide my visit from the US authorities and they can inspect my passport and interview me at will, but I don't want to get flagged or have anything appended to my travel history as it might cause unforeseen problems in the future.

Comment: If you are a young male with a Muslim name from a Muslim country, you are likely to be flagged regardless of your travels to Iraq or Iran. The CBP officers are reasonable. In the worst case scenario, you will get taken to secondary, and asked why you visited Iran and Iraq. As long as you have a reasonable explanation, you'll be free to go. Also, Iraq does not share any visa information with the USA.